# How to use a mask to normalize only non-black pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, gis

I have an RGB image loaded as an numpy.ndarray like the one here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT4CI.png).

I want to use opencv2 in python to normalise only non-black pixels, via the mask parameter. If not, then other ways would also be helpful.

I wanted to normalise the image initially
`cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)`

however then the normalisation of the coloured pixels is skewed by the black pixels and the colours aren't made as rich.

Instead I want to use a mask to normalise only the non-black pixels. I've tried the below but get the following error:

```
mask # This is an ndarray with dtype uint8 of the same shape as img, with values of 0 (mask) and 255 (not mask)
output_image = cv2.normalise(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, mask, -1)
```

```
(-215:Assertion failed) (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) || (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) in function 'cv::minMaxIdx
```

Answer (score 1):

The *cv2.normalize* function does not take a mask parameter. You can use the *cv2.inRange* function to create a mask from your image, then use that mask to select only the non-black pixels and normalize those.

```
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, 1, 255)
normalized = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
output_image = np.where(mask == 0, 0, normalized)
```

**cv2.inRange function only works with grayscale images.**

Comment: cv2.inRange() works on BGR images also. It is not limited to grayscale images!